# PHP MySQL image upload tmp to chosen directory

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

Ok, i want to upload an image from my computer to the host/database, everything works fine and it all uploads to the database (image name VARCHAR as to just be wording not image), except the image doesn't want to move and I get this warning:

```
Upload: 6285.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 68.1669921875 kB
Temp file: /tmp/php1Be59N

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/oils/6285.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/littlepe/public_html/pages/CMX/pages/extras/allFunctions.php on line 875

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/php1Be59N' to '/public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/oils/6285.jpg' in /home/littlepe/public_html/pages/CMX/pages/extras/allFunctions.php on line 875
Stored in: /public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/oils/6285.jpg Upload another? or Go home?
```

I have been through every type of directory, the first is the absolute path:

```
/home/public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/oils/6285.jpg
/public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/oils/6285.jpg
/pages/CMX/images/products/oils/6285.jpg
/CMX/images/products/oils/6285.jpg
/images/products/oils/6285.jpg
/products/oils/6285.jpg
/oils/6285.jpg
```

The directory is writeable and correct (I would show you but cannot post images as of yet).

My Form code:

```
    $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$sqlCommand = "(SELECT * FROM userAccount WHERE email='$user_check')";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCommand) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
$column = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if($column['admin'] != NULL){
    echo "<section class='userName'><h3>".$column['firstName']." ".$column['surname']."</h3></section>";
    echo "<section class='address'>".$column['addressLine1']."<br />".$column['addressLine2']."<br />".$column['county']."<br />".$column['country']."<br />".$column['postCode']."</section>";
    echo "<section class='email'><h3>".$column['email']."</h3></section>";
    echo "<hr />";
    echo "<section class='upNewProduct' style='height:400px;overflow:auto;'><h3>Upload New Product</h3>
        <form action='extras/uploadProcess.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Product Name: <input type='text' name='productName' /><br />
        Product Image Sub-Catagory: <select name='prodImgCat' id='prodImgCat'>
                    <option selected>Choose a Sub Catagory for Image</option>
                        <option value='oils/'>Oil</option>
                        <option value='chain/'>Chain</option>
                        <option value='coolant/'>Coolant</option>
                        <option value='filter/'>Filter</option>
                </select><br />
        Product Image: <input type='file' name='productImg' /><br />
        Description: <textarea type='text' name='shortDesc' value='' maxlength='1500' cols='22' rows='6' tabindex='6' id='shortDesc'></textarea><br />
        Features: <textarea type='text' name='longDesc' value='' maxlength='1500' cols='22' rows='6' tabindex='6' id='longDesc'></textarea><br />
        Price: <input type='text' name='price' /> <strong style='font-size:8pt;'>(Do <u>NOT</u> enter &pound; / &dollar; / &euro; currency symbols. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <u>ONLY</u> enter numerals. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <u>e.g:</u> 99.99 )</strong><br />
        Catagory: <select name='catagory' id='catagory'>
                    <option selected>Choose a Catagory</option>
                        <option value='Helmets'>Helmets</option>
                        <option value='Gloves'>Gloves</option>
                        <option value='Boots'>Boots</option>
                        <option value='Body Protection'>Body Protection</option>
                        <option value='Clothing'>Clothing</option>
                        <option value='Bike Parts'>Bike Parts</option>
                        <option value='Accessories'>Accessories</option>
                </select><br />
        Sub-Catagory: <select name='subCat' id='subCat'>
                    <option selected>Choose a Sub Catagory</option>
                        <option value='Oil'>Oil</option>
                        <option value='Chain'>Chain</option>
                        <option value='Coolant'>Coolant</option>
                </select><br />
        Brand: <select name='brand' id='brand'>
                    <option selected>Choose a brand</option>
                        <option value='100%'>100%</option>
                    <option value='Acerbis'>Acerbis</option>
                    <option value='Airoh'>Airoh</option>
                    <option value='Akrapovic'>Akrapovic</option>
                    <option value='Alias'>Alias</option>
                    <option value='Alpinestars'>Alpinestars</option>
                    <option value='Answer Racing'>Answer Racing</option>
                    <option value='Apico'>Apico</option>
                    <option value='Arai'>Arai</option>
                    <option value='Artrax'>Artrax</option>
                    <option value='Asterisk'>Asterisk</option>
                    <option value='Beer Optics'>Beer Optics</option>
                    <option value='Bell'>Bell</option>
                    <option value='Blackrock'>Blackrock</option>
                    <option value='Bolt'>Bolt</option>
                    <option value='Cycra'>Cycra</option>
                    <option value='Deft Family'>Deft Family</option>
                    <option value='DEP'>DEP</option>
                    <option value='Dragon'>Dragon</option>
                    <option value='DRC'>DRC</option>
                    <option value='Dunlop'>Dunlop</option>
                    <option value='EKS Brand'>EKS Brand</option>
                    <option value='Engine Ice'>Engine Ice</option>
                    <option value='EVS'>EVS</option>
                    <option value='Factory Arme'>Factory Arme</option>
                    <option value='Factory Effex'>Factory Effex</option>
                    <option value='Fly Racing'>Fly Racing</option>
                    <option value='Forcefield Armour'>Forcefield Armour</option>
                    <option value='Forma'>Forma</option>
                    <option value='Fro Systems'>Fro Systems</option>
                    <option value='Gaerne'>Gaerne</option>
                    <option value='Goldentyre'>Goldentyre</option>
                    <option value='GoPole'>GoPole</option>
                    <option value='GoPro'>GoPro</option>
                    <option value='HiFlo Filtro'>HiFlo Filtro</option>
                    <option value='JT Braking'>JT Braking</option>
                    <option value='K-Edge'>K-Edge</option>
                    <option value='Kryptonite'>Kryptonite</option>
                    <option value='Lazer'>Lazer</option>
                    <option value='Leatt'>Leatt</option>
                    <option value='Matrix Concepts'>Matrix Concepts</option>
                    <option value='Mechanix Wear'>Mechanix Wear</option>
                    <option value='Motion Pro'>Motion Pro</option>
                    <option value='Motorex'>Motorex</option>
                    <option value='Muc Off'>Muc Off</option>
                    <option value='No Toil'>No Toil</option>
                    <option value='Oakley'>Oakley</option>
                    <option value='ODI Troy Lee'>ODI Troy Lee</option>
                    <option value='Ogio'>Ogio</option>
                    <option value='One Industries'>One Industries</option>
                    <option value='Park Tool'>Park Tool</option>
                    <option value='POD'>POD</option>
                    <option value='Polisport'>Polisport</option>
                    <option value='Pro Clean'>Pro Clean</option>
                    <option value='Progrip'>Progrip</option>
                    <option value='Putoline'>Putoline</option>
                    <option value='Race FX'>Race FX</option>
                    <option value='Raptor Titanium'>Raptor Titanium</option>
                    <option value='Renthal'>Renthal</option>
                    <option value='Rip n Roll'>Rip n Roll</option>
                    <option value='Risk Racing'>Risk Racing</option>
                    <option value='RK Chains'>RK Chains</option>
                    <option value='SBS Brakes'>SBS Brakes</option>
                    <option value='Science in Sport'>Science in Sport</option>
                    <option value='Scott'>Scott</option>
                    <option value='Seven'>Seven</option>
                    <option value='Shoei'>Shoei</option>
                    <option value='Shot'>Shot</option>
                    <option value='Sidi'>Sidi</option>
                    <option value='SixSixOne'>SixSixOne</option>
                    <option value='SM Pro Platinum'>SM Pro Platinum</option>
                    <option value='Smith'>Smith</option>
                    <option value='Spada'>Spada</option>
                    <option value='Sunline'>Sunline</option>
                    <option value='Suomy'>Suomy</option>
                    <option value='THH'>THH</option>
                    <option value='Thor'>Thor</option>
                    <option value='Troy Lee Designs'>Troy Lee Designs</option>
                    <option value='Twin Air'>Twin Air</option>
                    <option value='Venhill'>Venhill</option>
                    <option value='VP Racing'>VP Racing</option>
                    <option value='Wizard Wash'>Wizard Wash</option>
                    <option value='Yoshimura'>Yoshimura</option>
                    <option value='Zeta'>Zeta</option>
                </select>
                <input id='contactBtn' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Product' tabindex='7' />
        </form>
    </section>";
```

My PHP code:

```
if (!$_POST['productName'] | !$_POST['prodImgCat'] | !$_POST['shortDesc'] | !$_POST['longDesc'] | !$_POST['price'] | !$_POST['catagory'] | !$_POST['subCat'] | !$_POST['brand']){
    die('You did not complete all of the required fields! <a href="http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/pages/userAccount.php">Try Again?</a>');
}

$productName = $_POST['productName'];
$prodImgCat = $_POST['prodImgCat'];
$shortDesc = $_POST['shortDesc'];
$longDesc = $_POST['longDesc'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$catagory = $_POST['catagory'];
$subCat = $_POST['subCat'];
$brand= $_POST['brand'];

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["productImg"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["productImg"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["productImg"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")|| ($_FILES["productImg"]["type"] == "image/jpg")|| ($_FILES["productImg"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")|| ($_FILES["productImg"]["type"] == "image/x-png")|| ($_FILES["productImg"]["type"] == "image/png"))&& ($_FILES["productImg"]["size"] < 200000)&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
    if ($_FILES["productImg"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["productImg"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }else{
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["productImg"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["productImg"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["productImg"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["productImg"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("/public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/".$_POST['prodImgCat'].$_FILES['productImg']['name']."")){
            echo $_FILES['productImg']['name']." already exists.";
        }else{
```

**!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! LINE 875 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImg']['tmp_name'], "/public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/".$_POST['prodImgCat'].$_FILES['productImg']['name']);
```

**!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

```
 echo "Stored in: "."/public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/".$_POST['prodImgCat'].$_FILES['productImg']['name']." <a href='http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/pages/userAccount.php'>Upload another?</a> or <a href='http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/pages/index.php'>Go home?</a>";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "Invalid file";
}

$productImgLocation = "".$_POST['prodImgCat']."".$_FILES['productImg']['name']."";

$insertProduct = ("INSERT INTO product (productName, productImg, shortDesc, longDesc, price, catagory, subCat, brand) VALUES ('".$_POST['productName']."', '".$productImgLocation."' '".$_POST['shortDesc']."', '".$_POST['longDesc']."', '".$_POST['price']."', '".$_POST['catagory']."', '".$_POST['subCat']."', '".$_POST['brand']."')");
$add_product = mysqli_query($con,$insertProduct);

mysqli_close($con);
```

So after all of that my question is this, what the flaming heck am I doing wrong here?, the file and directory are there and yet it doesn't want to move from the tmp folder to the chosen folder, please help as this is really starting to annoy me.

NOTE: My injection,etc. code is going to amended once i have completed the upload form, so please refrain from just posting about injections and the like, thank you.

Comment: which is line 875 ? and what the directory structure looks like ?

Comment: @egig I have edited my question to show 875 and the directory structure is shown with an absolute path above showing all the directories i have tried.

Comment: check your directory is not present in this location /public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/oils/ Also check the directory permission

Comment: the page which is executing the code cannot find the directory use this `./public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/".$_POST['prodImgCat'].$_FILES['productImg']['name']` or `../public_html/pages/CMX/images/products/".$_POST['prodImgCat'].$_FILES['productImg']['name']`

Comment: try to give path relative to the file getting executed. Are you using any sort of custom framework of your own? Which file does get executed?

Comment: The directory is correct, i have checked and rechecked it about 10 times now, and the permissions have been set to writable through filezilla, yet nothing..., I will try those too thank you

Comment: The destination file/directory needs to be owned by the same Linux owner and group as your web server (Apache?). Can you confirm in Filezilla (columns after chmod permissions). CHMOD won't have any effect if your user doesn't own it or have permissions.

Comment: And.. are you sure you have the full root path correct? Can you verify with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`? You surely need /home/ and there ought to be more parent folders than that (depending on your server environment)

Comment: @SetSailMedia you are a genius, thanks to looking into the phpinfo i found the answer, there WAS one more directory in between home and public_html, thank you :)